# application_error Server or HttpContext.Current.Server confusion

Tags: asp.net

I am confused over whether to use

```
Server.GetLastError
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError
```

in the `Application_Error` event.

Can someone please help me understand the differences between the two?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `Server.GetLastError` from the HttpApplication. In most cases, they are the same thing. Most ASP.NET base classes support the `Server` property as a shortcut to the current HttpContext's Server (Such as `HttpApplication` and `Page`). However, for the case of `HttpApplication`, if you are in a place where there is no HttpContext, it will create a new Server utility for you. For the case of `Page` and `UserControl`, they are exactly the same thing since you will always have an HttpContext no matter where you are in the life cycle.